# Interest of this idiom used in PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java

with colleagues, we were discussing the following idiom found in the code of `PriorityBlockingQueue` (Oracle JDK 8, v1.8.0_131). At almost every use of the field `private final ReentrantLock lock`, the developer has chosen to first store it in a local variable (defined as `final` too). The pattern looks like this:

```
... 
private final ReentrantLock lock; // initialized as 'new ReentrantLock()' in constructors
...

public E poll() {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock; // <--
    lock.lock();
```

This choice is difficult to explain, and none of us can see an advantage of this instead of using directly the field. Since the original field is `final`, this is not needed to prevent or reduce the risk of dirty reads in a multithreaded context. Since the field is not `volatile`, this is not an optimisation to access a volatile field only once. This could be a very tiny-micro-optimisation where a field reference lives in the heap and a local variable in the stack, and reading from the stack is (or could be?) a bit more efficient. But we are talking about at most picoseconds here. And this idiom is not used for others fields access - only the lock is managed this way...

So we are stuck at "*this is useless and could (should) be rewritten as direct field access*". But I'm a bit unconfortable with our conclusion. I know for sure that most of the code in the JDK is quite smart, and passed with success a few code reviews with top level engineering people. Are we missing some tricky implementation details here?